# Bootstrapping multiple regression parameters in Python

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression, statsmodels, statistics-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstraping to estimate multiple regression coefficients in Python, and I can't figure out how to implement it.

I use statsmodels.ols(formula = 'Y ~ A * B * C, ... ) to run a single model. How can I implement a bootstrap that will return estimates and confidence intervals for all of the parameters returned by this ordinary least squares model?

I see there's potentially a bootstrap method in statsmodels, but I can't figure out how to import it and if it has the functionality I want. There's another one (or a few) in scikits, but again, I can't figure out how to use these to estimate the many returned regression parameters.

Thanks for your help. I'm completely stumped -- and fairly new to Python.

Comment: statsmodels doesn't have much support for bootstrap. The arch package https://github.com/bashtage/arch#bootstrap contains some functions but more focused on time series analysis. Are you looking for a specific kind of bootstrap? If your A B C are categorical, then a nonparametric bootstrap (with random draws of observations) might often end up with singular design matrices. Parametric residual bootstrap might work. Is your sample size so small, that standard t confidence interval might not be accurate?

Comment: A and B are quantiative, C I've thrown out because I decided it just makes sense to do the regressions separately on the different categories for my purposes. Sample sizes should be sufficient for all of them....

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `resample` package that can be downloaded via `pip`.  Here's the Github page: https://github.com/dsaxton/resample.

In the `doc` folder there's a notebook that contains an example for precisely this kind of problem (here we're using `sklearn` but it can be adapted for `statsmodels` as well).  Essentially you define your modeling procedure as a function on the full data set (including both predictors and the response variable) which returns the model parameters in whatever format you like (here we're returning a dictionary with the coefficients and intercept) and then recompute the function on bootstrap samples using `bootstrap` from the `resample.bootstrap` module (`df` is a `pandas` `DataFrame` containing the predictors and `y` a `Series` with the response variable):

```
from resample.bootstrap import bootstrap
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def fitreg(A):
    scale = StandardScaler()
    reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
    X_scale = scale.fit_transform(A[:, :A.shape[1]-2])
    y = A[:, A.shape[1]-1]
    reg.fit(X_scale, y)
    return {"coef": reg.coef_, "intercept": reg.intercept_}

boot_coef = bootstrap(a=df.join(y).values, f=fitreg, b=5000)
```

Comment: In your code, b = 5000 indicates 5000 samples were used?